# Apt-get dist-upgrade fails

Tags: linux-mint, apt, upgrade, mate-desktop

I'm trying to upgrade from Mint 13 to Mint 15, but receive the following error:

```
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mate-media : Depends: mate-media-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed or
                       mate-media-pulse but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

It seems that `mate-media-gstreamer` and `mate-media-pulse` conflict with each other. Could someone help with this?

Comment: **CAREFUL** if you installed graphic drivers (like nvidia's) with apt-get **I highly recommend you to not upgrade**, when I did that I got a new version of X which wasn't compatible with the driver, end up without graphical interface for a few days before I was able to uninstall the old driver and install a new one.

Comment: thanks, I will download now the new version of the driver

Comment: before reporting bug, please use `apt-get update` before `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install mate-media-gstreamer`. I find that sometimes that gives additional info on why things aren't being installed.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend upgrading from Mint 13 to Mint 15. Mint doesn't take a lot of care to make upgrade smooth, and skipping a version increases the risk of problems. Upgrade to Mint 14 first.

When you have upgrade trouble with `apt-get`, try `aptitude`. It often uses different conflict resolution algorithms, and depending on the version one or the other may be better at resolving conflicts. Aptitude also gives you a nicer interface to try and resolve conflicts.

It may be worth uninstalling a few packages that cause trouble (e.g. `mate-media`), then doing the upgrade, and finally reinstalling the removed packages.